# Equivalent INNER JOIN query in DAX

Tags: t-sql, powerbi, dax

I have this following query in TSQL :

```
SELECT
CustomerName,
SumOfSales
FROM (
SELECT
Customers.CustomerName,
SUM ( Sales.SalesAmount ) AS SumOfSales
FROM
Sales
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Sales.CustomerKey = Customers.CustomerKey
GROUP BY
Customers.CustomerName
) AS SubQuery
WHERE
SubQuery.SumOfSales > 100
```

I am working on Power BI and querying the table from SQL Server.
I want to create the same dax query to retrieve customers and total sales for only the customers who bought morethan 100 euros. How to do the INNER JOIN in Power BI ?

Answer (score 2):

DAX uses an automatic LEFT OUTER JOIN in the query whenever you use columns related to the primary table :

```
EVALUATE
FILTER (
SUMMARIZE (
YourTable,
YourTable[CustomerName],
"TotalOver100", SUM ( Sales[SalesAmount] )
),
[TotalOver100] > 100
```